# Step Activation function...why does it work?!

Tags: calculus, machine-learning, neural-networks

I enjoy watching a channel called "Coding Train" because he does his work very informative and with an energy I can only envy. He did a video on neural networks and I'm kinda stumped on why it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntKn5TPHHAk
In this he does a NN as easy as it can be, using a step function as the activation function. However I don't get why this works at all. The derivative should be 0 everywhere (assuming you define it yourself at point 0). So why does his "backpropagation" work? When you look at how he changes the weights it's not as in gradient descent at all is it? The partial derivatives of the gradient should be 0, therefore giving you nothing to optimize the weights right?

Can you please help solve my confusion? :D

Bonus question: If I somehow am wrong regarding the step function...why does his cost function work? Using gradient descent you try to optimize the cost function. However his cost function is C = label - prediction...this is linear so shouldn't have a minimum to descent to (or rather having infinity as minimum). However his Code still does the job he wants it to. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, back-propagation with gradient descent(and  its variants) requires the activation functions of all units to be differentiable (or differentiable in a piece wise fashion i.e. ReLU) in a neural network. Hence the step function can't (and wouldn't) want to be used.

However, the perceptron classifier (defined as using the step activation function) has a different learning algorithm and is not the same as that of a neural network. (see [Wikpedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) for more info about the algorithm).

Comment: ahh Thanks :D I was sort of poking into the right thing but didn't know that Perceptron works differently than MLP regarding the learning algorithm

Comment: Np. The term "multi-layer perceptron" for neural networks confusingly refers to the fact that the affine function of component of the perceptron and the concept of an "activation function" is still used for neural networks.